# VALIDATION ERROR! Validation check if email address already exist in the db phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

If the email address is already exists in the database, so the program should not be executed and display the error of "Email already registered", but its not working like that. Code looks fine to me no syntax error. But not working like I want instead of showing me the error of email exist. It executes the form and insert duplicate email address in the mysql database.

Here is the code, Please let me know if anyone can helps.

```
<?php
include('dbconnection.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['rSignup'])){
    if(($_REQUEST['rName'] == "") || ($_REQUEST['rEmail'] =="") || ($_REQUEST['rPassword'] =="")){
        $regmsg = '<div class="alert alert-warning mt-2" role="alert">All Fields are Required</div>';
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT r_email FROM requestorlogin_tb WHERE r_email='".$_REQUEST['rEmail']."'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows==1){
            $regmsg = '<div class="alert alert-warning mt-2" role="alert">Email ID Already Registered</div>';
        } else{
            $rName = $_REQUEST['rName'];
            $rEmail = $_REQUEST['rEmail'];
            $rPassword = $_REQUEST['rPassword'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO requesterlogin_tb(r_name,r_email,r_password) VALUES('$rName','$rEmail','$rPassword')";
            if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE){
                $regmsg = '<div class="alert alert-success mt-2" role="alert">Account Successfully Created</div>';
            } else{
                $regmsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" role="alert">Unable to Create Account</div>';
                }
            }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: add a unique constraint on the database and then the duplicate email can't be inserted, regardless of what your php does

Comment: I suspect your issue lies here:

`$result->num_rows==1`

unless you are clearing out the database each time?  You probably want to check if
 
`$result->num_rows > 0`

Comment: and then you want to go and research prepared statements,  because this: `WHERE r_email='".$_REQUEST['rEmail']."'"` is a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: So should I try this:$result->num_rows > 0

Comment: I have change it but not working and there is an error,

Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\NewOSMS\UserRegistration.php on line 9

Answer (score 1):

Please update your query for prevent sql inject and try that :

```
  $remail=$_REQUEST['rEmail'];
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT r_email FROM requestorlogin_tb WHERE r_email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $remail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // Assign the result to a variable

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // Check the number of rows in the MySQLi result object
        echo "exist";
        
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    } else {
    ....
```

Comment: Simone, It didn't inserted the duplicate email in the database but instead of this there was a n error.

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\NewOSMS\UserRegistration.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewOSMS\index.php(76): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\NewOSMS\UserRegistration.php on line 9

Comment: are you sure include path is good? connection file is properly set?